# css animation loop needed for <li> elements

Tags: html, css

I have finally managed to stop the list blurring for a brief second when it hits the breakpoint, but how do I now loop the list?  At the moment it ends after the last bullet point.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

    li {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        opacity: 0;


        animation: fadeOut 3s ease-out forwards ;



        -webkit-animation: fadeOut 3s ease-out forwards;
        animation: fadeOut 3s ease-out forwards ;





    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
    @keyframes fadeOut {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;

        }
        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    li:nth-child(1) {
        animation-delay: 0s;

    }

    li:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }

    li:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }

    li:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 9s;
    }

}
```

Ideally I don't want to use JS so would I have to set up a keyframe event each LI's fade in/out?  Here is a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1gvywmda/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the answer:

https://jsfiddle.net/jwc9rem5/3/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {  
    .usp-line li:first-child {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .usp-line li:not(:first-child) {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .7s;
    }
}
```

Comment: The transition makes each bullet point fade in/out nicely rather than just vanish then next one appear.

Comment: This will get closer to what you want.

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue.  As the screen resizes to 1023 you can see it all blurs as they show in the middle

Comment: This is different. The overlap happens because the first child that needs to be in the middle, is moved there. BUT the effect is not the same. the others fade in place.

Comment: It is the blur when they all merge that is the problem.  The moment all four become one is when there is moment of blur

Answer (score 0):

give all your li `position: relative;`

```
.usp-line li {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .7s;
}
```

And try removing the `line-height` property from `.usp-line`

Comment: I have done this but now when you resize the screen three of the bullet points appear beneath the main one before vanishing.

Comment: your code works fine for me, i dont know what exactly is the issue , until you post some pics

Comment: @Nathan what should the other li do, when it  reaches the break point?

Comment: The issue is not about what it should do before it reaches 1023 or after, it is the blur you can see at the breakpoint for a split second. It isn't possible to show a pic as the transition kicks in and shows just one bullet point (as it should).  It is that moment just before when each bullet is on top of each other